# java - dynamic casting using strings

Tags: java, android, cursor

Consider a sqlite database table `DRINK` with columns: `Name`(String), `Description`(String), `ResourceID`(int).

Now, after I get a `Cursor cur` everytime I'd like to get something out of a particular row, I'd have to do something like:

```
cur = db.query(...);
String name = cur.getString(0);
String desc = cur.getString(1);
int desc = cur.getInt(0);
```

But, this logic is so dependent on my knowledge of knowing the database table schema and I'd like to avoig that. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
Object x = cur.getObject(0); //not available
```

but, as marked the `getObject` is not available to a cursor

but, I also require while doing this the data types are also preserved, meaning, a `1` stored as `integer` in its `ResourceID` column, does not give `1 instanceOf String=true`, it should give `1 instanceOf int=true`.

so, why would I want to do that? If I can do this, then I can obtain values from the database in something like a for loop without having the worry what is in the schema and providing only it's length.

What are the ways this can be achieved, or atleast achieving a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`getType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getType(int)) then use a `switch` statement to call the appropriate `getXxx()` method.

Comment: bingo! just what I wanted, but just a slight confusion I found in the doc in this line: ` The preferred type of the column is returned but the data may be converted to other types as documented in the get-type methods such as getInt(int)` , meaning if we use getInt(ResourceID), where ResourceID is a string is it automatically converted to an int?

Comment: @juztcode It means that just because `getType("ResourceID")` returns a value saying the type is an integer, it doesn't mean you *must* call `getInt()`. You can still call `getString()` and `getDouble()`, and the integer value will be converted for you.

Comment: just came across this int the given link , what is a `FIELD_TYPE_BLOB`, the doc only says: `Value returned by getType(int) if the specified column type is blob`. What sort of value is a blob?

Comment: @juztcode Each of the types has a corresponding getter method, so if you take a look at the documentation for the `getBlob()` method, you might learn more.